# c# the name 'xy' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I just started with C# at work and I did read like a lot of the questions that are about my error here at StackOverflow. Unfortunately I still don't get what I'm doing wrong.

So, I followed this (http://qafriend.com/c-ui-automation-tutorial/automate-using-c-tutorial-guide-part-5) tutorial that is about C# and UI Automation. Everything went fine until I had to write actual code. So my code is this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using Automation = System.Windows.Automation;

namespace AutomateCSharp
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    static AutomationElement desktopObject = AutomationElement.RootElement;

    static Automation.Condition testWindowNameCondition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Demo Window For Csharp Automation");
    static Automation.Condition textConditionOne = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "InputOne");
    static Automation.Condition textConditionTwo = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "InputTwo");
    static Automation.Condition textConditionTotal = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "Total");

    static AutomationElement testWindow = desktopObject.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, testWindowNameCondition);

    static AutomationElement textOne = testWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, textConditionOne);
    static ValuePattern valuetextOne = textOne.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;
    valuetextOne.SetValue("4");

    }
}
```

And I get the Error: The name 'valuetextOne' does not exist in the current context.

Could someone please tell me what I'm wrong about? Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: I'd recommend you to start with the [Microsoft Docs documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/). What's wrong is that you cannot put code outside of a method. Also, your code is not the same as the tutorial you linked, so...

Comment: Thanks, I'm being blind today, was wondering why that works outside a method already, but I thought thats some C# magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has to do with the fact that functions can't be called inside class bodies directly. Only fields, properties and methods can be written there. What you need to do, is wrap it inside another function, like so:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // Stuff
    public void SetValue() => valuetextOne.SetValue("4");
}
```

And then you call it as:

```
public void Foo()
{
    MainWindow window = Bar();
    window.SetValue();
}
```

I go into more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381956/dosent-exist-in-the-current-context/50382015#50382015) about this.