# Dosen't exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having an issue in C# in my accountcontroller.

```
   public class Authenticateuser
{
    int Userid = 0;
    static string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbPCTECH"].ConnectionString;
    public MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
    Connection.open;
```

connection.open is raising the exception, that it's not in the current context. What's causing this? I have tried changing names, etc. I've never had this issue.

Comment: Did you mean to call `connection.Open()`?

Comment: You should use `connection.Open()`. C# variable names are case-sensitive.

Comment: Also you cannot put code directly at class level, that last line would need to be in a method.

Comment: The last time I used this code, and it worked I put it in an ActionResult, so would that be different than calling it in a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three main problems:

1. **C# is case sensitive**
2. **You must add `()` add the end of a function name to call it**
3. **The function call must be inside another function, not in the class declaration**

In C#, `Connection` is different than `connection`. There are times when you would want to use the different casing to differentiate between two members, such as full Properties, but besides that, it is bad to have `connection` and `conNectIOn`, even though it wll work.

Also, to call a function or method, you need to use the `()` at the end of the name, so you'd do `connection.Open();`

**EDIT**:
Problem 3 is a bit more complicated. Here's your class:

```
public class Authenticateuser
{
    public MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connstring);

    private static string connstring = ConfigurationManager
        .ConnectionStrings["dbPCTECH"].ConnectionString;
    private int Userid = 0;

    connection.Open;
}
```

I refactored the code a little bit to be in a more conventional order, `public` members on top, `private` members on bottom, `static` members above non-static. If you don't use `private` it will default to `private` but I prefer being explict in the typing.

Anyways, this problem has to do with the fact that functions can't be called inside class bodies *directly*. Only fields, properties and methods can be written there. What you need to do, is wrap it inside another function, like so:

```
public class Authenticateuser
{
    public MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connstring);

    private static string connstring = ConfigurationManager
        .ConnectionStrings["dbPCTECH"].ConnectionString;
    private int Userid = 0;

    public Open() => connection.Open();
}
```

Also,

```
public Open() => connection.Open();
```

Is the exact same as:

```
public Open() 
{
    connection.Open();
}
```

Just cleaner. This should work. You then call it like this:

```
var auth = new Authenticatuser();
auth.Open();
```

It is also generally considered better to do `auth.Open();` than `auth.connection.Open();`. This is because, in real life, you don't tell the dogs legs to move, you tell the dog to move, and the dog tells it's own legs to move.

Comment: I put it lowercase, and i put the () at the end, but still get the same result. when i'm typing the function, you know how it'll usually pickup what you're typing? it dosen't even find it.

Comment: I updated my answer, see if that works

Comment: Thank you so much AustinWBryan! I really appreciate your response, as it's truly helped me. C# is a new beast to me, and people like you have really helped me out!